# Find in a hash any values greater then a specific value

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have this hash

```
{ 1 => 4 , 2 => 3 , 4 => 1}
```

Now I want to make a loop where I can find any value which is greater then 3.

I know with `hash.values?3` I can find the pairs has a value of 3.
But how can I find all the values which are greater of equal as 3.

Roelof

Edit 1 : 
I try to make this pseudo code at work in ruby.

```
while there are sets of 3 ones:
  remove the set from the hash (h[1] -= 3)
  sum 1000 to the score
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `#select` method:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.select{|k,v| v > 1}
```

Comment: +1 for `#select`. To return only the values, and not key:values, @Kern Twente can use `your_hash.values.select{|v| v >= 3}`